# Substitute webview in PhoneGap for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, webview

(re-post from the PG google group)

I know there's been a lot of conversation on this in the past, but I've been researching it for the past few days and couldn't seem to find a definitive answer (or even what it would entail).

I was wondering how plausible it would be to embed a snapshot build of the Chrome webview (or even the Gecko webview) into a Phonegap app and to use that in place of the native webview that PhoneGap uses. The problem is twofold - 1) Android's native browser/webview is terrible and 2) Each phone seems to have idiosyncratic bugs/differences, which having one set snapshot to build against would fix.

I've seen answers ranging from "Oh, yeah, just build the source and drop it in" to "You'd need a full team of Java devs to hack the PhoneGap API core to get it to work". Does anyone have an answer of what it would entail, how much time it would take, if it's even plausible, etc? I suppose the biggest concern is - given we can get a snapshot build of the Chrome webview, does that break any of the connections to the PhoneGap APIs? Are they tied specifically to the native webview?

Any and all thoughts are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has the ability to be embedded by use of the [Content Module](http://www.chromium.org/developers/content-module).  In theory (I have never done it) you can build this and embed it into your Application and use that instead of a WebView - it has the advantage of being an up to date Chrome and multi-process.  It loses value in that it can't be used pre-Jellybean.

Comment: But will that break the use of PhoneGap APIs? Are they tied specifically to the native webview? The pre-4.0 issue isn't really relevant for us considering our SSL certs don't work pre-4.0 either, so that's a bigger problem